# mutate data frame if cells are empty

Tags: r

I have a data frame like below, I want to give `DEPT_Head = "DEV0001"`  dynamically to my script

```
df <- data.frame(HOD_ID =c("","KTN2252","ANA2719","ITI2624","DEV2698","HRT2921","","KTN2624","ANA2548","ITI2535","DEV2732","HRT2837","ERV2951","KTN2542","ANA2813","ITI2210"),
                 DEPT_Head = c("DEV0001","KTN2252","ANA2719","ITI2624","DEV2698","HRT2921","ERV0000","KTN2624","ANA2548","ITI2535","DEV2732","HRT2837","ERV2951","KTN2542","ANA2813","ITI2210"))
```

My code always required input parameters
`DEPT_Head = "DEV0001"`

Now I want to mutate my data frame if `HOD_ID` for user input `Dept_head` should be blank, and if there are any other blank cells except user input parameters the mutate new column to 1
`HOD_I`D should always be blank for user-defined `DEPT_Head`, else if there any blank cells then mutate `if_blank` to 1

First check `Dept_head` should be empty for `HOD_ID` provided by the user as input parameters.
Second is other than user input `dept_head` id there should not be any empty cells, if found any empty cell then mutate new column to 1

Comment: will this do? df %>% mutate(if_blank = case_when(HOD_ID == '' & DEPT_Head != "DEV0001" ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0))

Comment: yes this is not working for me thats why i am looking for solution

Comment: What do you want to do if `HOD_ID` is not empty for `DEPT_Head` provided?

Comment: that can be empty , so for that no mutation only 0 in mutated column, after that 1 for all empty cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try :

```
DEPT_Head = "DEV0001"
df$if_blank <- as.integer(df$DEPT_Head != DEPT_Head & df$HOD_ID == '')
```